# Solution for using latexdiff on files with toggles

Tags: etoolbox, latexdiff

I have different versions of a latex file that use toggles (from `etoolbox`). When I use latexdiff to compare the different versions, I can see that latexdiff is (practically) oblivious to changes in values of the toggles. For example, with `file1.tex` and `file2.tex` given below, the output of the latexdiff file (after compiling) is simply "content when boolFlag is true".

File 1.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\providetoggle{boolFlag}

\iftoggle{boolFlag}
{content when boolFlag is true}
{content when boolFlag is false}
\end{document}
```

File2.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\providetoggle{boolFlag}
\toggletrue{boolFlag}

\iftoggle{boolFlag}
{content when boolFlag is true}
{content when boolFlag is false}
\end{document}
```

The expected output is "content when boolFlag is <s>false</s> **true**".

**How to get this correct latexdiff output?**

The solutions I expect are

1. A way to generate a file with replaced content when given the
   latex file with toggles, and the list of toggle variable values (similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513320/157031), but with LaTeX rather than LuaLaTeX).
2. Somehow make latexdiff aware of toggles (I suppose this is going to be hard; great if such a solution exists).

Comment: As the developer/maintainer of latexdiff I would strongly favour solution 1. The only alternative would really be to reimplement the full toggle functionality as an internal pre-processor within latexdiff. Sorry to not be able to help further.

Comment: @frederik Thanks for the input. Latexdiff reimplementing toggle is a good idea. But, I am afraid audience for this functionality would be too small. How about using tex primitives instead of toggle? I suppose that that's not going to help either.